# Hiding an id from codeigniter URL not displaying the id in form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having career page where I am displaying all the job posts and from there the users can apply for the particular job.
Clicking on "Applynow" button it will display a form of the user details what he needs to be filled along with the job position name.In the URL, it will display it as

www.testing.com/career/apply/1

Career is the controller and apply is the function name and 1 is the id which I am passing.But in URL I need to display only this.

> www.testing.com/career/apply

For this purpose i have written in application/config/routes.php i just added this:

```
$route['(:num)/(:num)/(:num)/(:num)'] = 'career/apply/$1/$2/$3/$4';
```

After adding this in URL it is not displaying the id but I need to display that is in **applynow** form. After adding this it is not displaying the form.

Career View:

```
<?php if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
<?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>                  
<span class="digit"><?php echo $r->job_name ;?></span>
<div class="applynow">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>career/apply/<?php echo $r->jobs_id;?>" class="applyforjob">Apply Now</a>
</div>
<?php endforeach; endif;?>
```

Career/apply:

```
function apply($job_id)
{
    $this->load->model('career_model');
    $data['records2']= $this->career_model->getcareerdatas($job_id);        
    $data['mainpage']='apply';      
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

View:

```
<?php if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
<?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>              

<div class="applyposition ">
    <input type="text" class="form-control positionapplied" name="positionapplied" id="positionapplied " value="<?php echo $r->job_name ;?>" readonly>                          
</div>  
<?php endforeach;endif;?>
```

If I remove the line routes.php file it is displaying the "job title" name but in URL I should not display the id.

Comment: Need to display the jobname in form but should not display the id in URL

Comment: Make querying from database by slug which should be stored in column (if not already there) by job title and some other logic if needed. For that you need lot of changes in your controller/model/view files. And as side note, you should leave ID as identifier even if you are using slug component in URL.

Comment: Can anyone help me out this one.Thanks in advance

Comment: send id in hidden field

Comment: Not getting you i have written the code for that but it is hiding the name

Comment: @user7596840 if i give input type="hidden" then the value will not be displayed but i need to display the job name in form